# 301 rewrite rule to add slash in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This is unusual question i guess.
We have done complete redirect 301 from old website to new one, except this one.
When any user adds any unwanted parameters to the end of old website page it redirects to 404 error page. 
For example: Old website name: www.example.com.au
New website name: www.example1.com.au

so when someone type example.com.au/test [here webpage 'test' doesn't exist]
it redirects to example1.com.autest

It want to add '/' before test, so it redirects to example1.com.au/test which would give proper 404 error page.

I hope i've explained properly.
Your inputs for a solution would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,
Ari

Comment: I tried few rewrite rules for this in .htaccess file but doesn't seem to be working. I think I'm not doing it right .

Comment: You could reveal some code you tested

Answer (score 0):

In my library I have this: ([found here](http://perishablepress.com/code-snippets/) - didn't test it myself)

```
# Always having a trailing slash  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$  
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```